# Why put require statement at the end of a ruby file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, require

I saw this in my newly inherited ruby/rails project,
and was wondering:

```
module Canonicalizer
  # Redirects the client to the canonical url
  #
  # @return [undefined]
  #
  # @api private
  def redirect_to_canonical_url
    if request.get? && !canonical_url?
      redirect_to canonical_url, status: :moved_permanently
      false
    else
      true
    end
  end

  # Test if the current request URL is canonical
  #
  # @return [Boolean]
  #
  # @api private
  def canonical_url?
    request.path == canonical_url
  end

end

require 'canonicalizer/hub_page_canonical'
```

Comment: Where does that code come from?

Comment: a private repo for a website based on rails

Comment: Maybe the required code expects `Canonicalizer` or the methods within it to be defined. Have you checked the source code or tried moving `require` to the top?

Comment: One can only speculate. Maybe its location was necessary to avoid a conflict in the module definition, or possibly the opposite: to tell the reader that the module definition does not depend on what is being required. Maybe it was to delay its execution until needed. Most of us are used to putting `require` statements near the top of a file, but might it be better practice to put each one immediately before the first block of code where it is needed?

Answer (score 6):

Ruby code is not compiled, it’s being processed [mostly] as it comes to the parser. That said, the following two pieces of code are not equivalent:

```
class Foo; def foo; :first; end; end
class Foo; def foo; :second; end; end
Foo.new.foo #⇒ :second
```

vs.

```
class Foo; def foo; :second; end; end
class Foo; def foo; :first; end; end
Foo.new.foo #⇒ :first
```

Also, [`Kernel#require`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-require) is a regular function defined on `Kernel` module. I could think of `'canonicalizer/hub_page_canonical'` file depends on `Canonicalizer` module (e. g. it contains the definition of the class that `include Canonicalizer`.) For that to be possible, the included module must be declared upfront, hence `require` comes after its definition.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that that there is something happening when the library is required via `require 'canonicalizer/hub_page_canonical'` that acts differently if those methods aren't defined on `module Canonicalizer`.

Could be metaprogramming of some type or just that those methods are called at code load time.

Ruby is a language where code can run both at load time and run time.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange to see a `require` in a rails app, that shouldn't be there. That being said, a reason I had to do this was to avoid an infinite loop, when one file required the other in order to resolve their constants (via rails autoloader).

My suggestion would be to forget about this, remove all `require`s you see and use standard autoload via convention of files and folder names.